# Can I use my new user form to log in too

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This has been asked before to some degree but I couldn't find an actual answer: How can I allow my users to log in via the same form they signup? This is a client request/demand by the way, I realise this is far from ideal...

**User**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      render :json => @user.to_json(:only => [:id])
    else
      render :json => @user.errors, :status => ""
    end
  end
end
```

**Session**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:email])
      sign_in user
      render :json => @user.to_json(:only => [:id])
    else
      render :json => @user.errors, :status => ""
    end
  end
end
```

**Form**

```
<%= form_for(@user, :html => { :class => "access"}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :firstname, "Firstname" %>
    <%= f.text_field :firstname, :placeholder => "Your firstname" %>
    <%= f.label :surname, "Surname" %>
    <%= f.text_field :surname, :placeholder => "Your surname" %>
    <%= f.label :email, "Email Address" %>
    <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Your email address" %>
    <%= f.submit "Verify" %>
<% end %>
```

Emails are validated as unique, could that be an entry point? Eg. If the email is not unique check the name and email or something.

I have no idea how to go about this.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do here because log in & register are two difference process. If user tries to register with an existing email then you can let user know that you are registered & prompt for password.

Comment: Yeah, I know they're different that's why I'm stuck. Basically there is no password, you just log in with name and email. So what I want is if you don't exist you're created but if you do you're logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to make another controller which is something like `AccessController`.  It should use a name that means both login and register, Access was just all I could think of.  That controller should be able to do a check on the login credentials and either login or register.